Vega 8 not working with my Type-C to HDMI adapter
My specs:
HP ENVY X360
Quist Type-C to HDMI
Asus Monitor
Updated Drivers for Vega 8
my monitor is getting detected by windows: settings
Monitor shows up in settings, but when I turn monitor on, the actual monitor cant detect any video etc so it just turns off after 5 seconds. Any idea why this is happening to me, how can I resolve it?
using windows 11.
